# Traefik - Object not found 404

Tags: traefik

i have these rules:

```
[backends]
  [backends.pma]
    [backends.pma.servers.server1]
    url = "http://phpmyadmin:80"
  [backends.rabbitmq]
    [backends.rabbitmq.servers.server1]
    url = "http://rabbitmq:15672"

[frontends]
  [frontends.pma]
  backend = "pma"
    [frontends.pma.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host:pma.example.it"
    passHostHeader = true
  [frontends.rabbitmq]
  backend = "rabbitmq"
    [frontends.rabbitmq.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host:pma.example.it;Path:/rabbitmq"
```

The host pma.example.it work, i see phpmyadmin, the host pma.example.it/rabbitmq not work, i have `{"error":"Object Not Found","reason":"Not Found"}`.

But, from traefik container if I type `curl http://rabbitmq:15672` it work's. Any ideas?

Comment: I have tried but have 404, I see in Firefox development tools `http://pma.example.it/start.js` instead of `http://pma.example.it/rabbitmq/start.js`

Answer (score 2):

Could you try to use `PathPrefix` instead of `Path` as rule.

Note, you have a small typo in your configuration:

```
[backends]
  [backends.pma] # <---
  [backends.pma.servers.server1]
    url = "http://phpmyadmin:80"

[backends.rabbitmq] # <---
  [backends.rabbitmq.servers.server1]
    url = "http://rabbitmq:15672"

[frontends]
  [frontends.pma]
  backend = "pma"
    [frontends.pma.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host:pma.example.it"
    passHostHeader = true
  [frontends.rabbitmq]
  backend = "rabbitmq"
    [frontends.rabbitmq.routes.test_1]
    rule = "Host:pma.example.it;Path:/rabbitmq"
```

Comment: Not work, same error, now i create a new domain for rabbitmq, instead to use a path

Answer (score 1):

The path in your two examples aren't equal. When you go to `pma.example.it/rabbitmq`, your RabbitMQ instance is effectively receiving `rabbitmq:15672/rabbitmq`, and returning the `Object Not Found` error.

You probably want `PathPrefixStrip` instead of `Path` in your frontend rule. It'll match on paths beginning with `/rabbitmq`, and strip that before passing it to the backend.

```
rule = "Host:pma.example.it;PathPrefixStrip:/rabbitmq"
```

Answer (score 1):

PathPrefixStrip won't work, because the main page of management console loads static files using the stripped url, causing responses with status 404. 
I had similar problem and fixed it by setting path prefix in rabbitmq.conf. In your case it would be:

`management.path_prefix = /rabbitmq`

The configuration of Traefik stays unchanged.

See also https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#path-prefix

Answer (score -3):

There is a missing line in backend config

```
[backends]
   [backends.pma]
   [backends.pma.servers]      # <----------add this
      [backends.pma.servers.server1]
         url = "http://phpmyadmin:80"
```

(same for backend.rabbitmq)

Comment: this line is not necessary, pma.example.it works, I follow these examples https://docs.traefik.io/basics/